# Is it there an alternative to Navigation for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I working on an Android App using Xamarin.Forms. I have a few problems with the navigation.

When I use `Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage());` my navigation flow creates bucles. When I press go back, I revisit pages that sould be inaccesables. For example I push this pages:

Login (go)> Menu (go)> CloseSession (go)> Login

When I click the go back button of Android, the flow is this:

Login (go)> Menu (go)> CloseSession (go)> Login (goback)> CloseSession (goback)> Menu (goback)> Login

insted of going out of the App:

Login (go)> Menu (go)> CloseSession (go)> Login (goback)> App close

I know if I use `Navigation.PopAsync();` the last push page is remove from the navigetion stack but it look tricky for me. Is it there an alternative to Navigation for Xamarin? Some way to create navigate pages avoiding adding them into the stack?

Comment: Other than creating a new navigation stack, two options: 1. [Remove after adding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack). 2. Using Xamarin Shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is "**manipulating the navigation stack**".

- If you don't want a page to be on the navigation stack you can remove it as soon as you navigate away from it using `Navigation.RemovePage(page)`.
  You can pass a saved reference of that page, or look it up in the `Navigation.NavigationStack`, if it's a known scenario (known navigation stack index of the page you want to remove) you can do:

  Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[index]);
- Or you can use `InsertPageBefore()` followed by a `PopAsync()` as shown in the [navigation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack) example:

> These methods enable a custom navigation experience, such as replacing a login page with a new page, following a successful login. The following code example demonstrates this scenario:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsValid)
  {
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage (), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
  }

 else
 {
    // Login failed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use navigation like this.    Some forms (especially login), should be popped when completed.

1. Push login form
2. User Completes login
3. Pop login form
4. Decide which form should be pushed next.

Comment: Is there a way to navigate with out using the stack? Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would guess it's pretty much a requirement to use Navigation.  You just need to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario I suggest you use [Modal Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal) to present the login page .

It will create **an extra modal stack**  which will not affect the original stack.

When user complete login , then pop the login page .

---

The flow

- Set `NavigationPage(root page : Main)` as MainPage in App.
- Show login page using `PushModalAsync`  .
- Complete login
- Close login page using `PopModalAsync`.

Comment: But with the go back button on Android I can avoid the login.