# Design recommendations for Xamarin Forms Login scenario

Tags: xamarin

I am looking for some best practice advice. I have a mobile application that has 4 functional elements. Out of the 4 only 1 requires the user to be authenticated.

For the authentication I have built a login page. So first I am checking if an application level property is setup. If that is true then the app does not need authentication. If that is not set I am loading a login form hosted on a content page.

The login page/ form has a backing ViewModel.

The PROBLEM I am trying to solve is that after the user has logged in from the login page and navigates to the next page, the back button takes user back to the login page.

The scenario I would like is that when user reaches a specific page, from that page back should go back to another page not the login page.

MainPage --> Login --> Dashboard

Dashboard(Back) --> Login (Not desired)

**Dashboard(Back) --> MainPage (Desired)**

Can somebody please help with this? I am looking for some guidance.

Regards.

Comment: you can remove pages from the NavigationStack to prevent/control back navigation.  It is also a common scenario to reassign the value of MainPage after Login to prevent back Navigation

Comment: is there an example of how this is done? a tutorial perhaps?

Comment: `App.Current.MainPage = new MyNewFirstPage();`, or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it there an alternative to Navigation for Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157856/is-it-there-an-alternative-to-navigation-for-xamarin)

Comment: Don't get confused by the linked question title I believe it is the same issue/question.